# Two network all for one fetch command

Tags: rest, fetch, redux-saga

I am using Redux-Sagas and here is what I am experiencing.

I am not sure if it is expected or not.

Every time the code trigger saga run a fetch command, it actually is showing two request.

I have custom header for the request.
I did try to remove x-custom-header and it showed one request.

What could be wrong here?

Thanks,

[Please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucYDr.png)

Answer (score 1):

The first request is most probably an HTTP 'OPTIONS' (Preflight) request that is automatically done by the browser for cross origin requests.

Please see this article for an explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests